# Setting up django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have setup my Django rest framework and started with my initial tutorial..Its running fine , but

I get this msg when I run it--

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

I have one user being setup ..Not sure I dont see in the resultset. When I go to shell and try User.objects.all(), I see that user.

Comment: Do you have this in settings.py? 
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
    )
}

Answer (score 0):

I apologise if your problem is not be this simple, but have you authenticated with your Django site?

A quick way to get moving; go to the Django admin console, log in and then go to your API.

In older versions of Django you will have to enable the admin console in [project]/settings.py and [project]/urls.py.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/

I tend to have both open in separate tabs when I am building, and when I first started with rest_framework I didn't even realise that the tutorial leverages the django auth by default until I got to the auth part of the tute. I felt a bit silly being so complacent with how well some of this current gen tech works these days!